# @media screen for small screen is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I created an html file and css file. on *larger screen* I want the text "I LOVE CODING, I WILL BECOME AN EXPERT."
to be **blue text on red background**
while on *small screen* it will be **green text on yellow background**.
But on both small and large screen the result is *'blue text on red background'*

BELOW IS MY HTML CODE

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Banking</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="myCurrent.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test"><p>I LOVE CODING, I WILL BECOME AN EXPERT.</p></div>
</body>
</html>```

AND HERE IS MY CSS CODE
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(169, 223, 242);
}

@media all and (max-width: 56.25em) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .test {
        color: green;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

.test {
    color: blue;
    background-color: red;
}

.box-txt {
    text-align: center;
    color: whitesmoke;
}


What worried me the most is that the style on 'body' element worked well on both small and larger screen (on large screen the body background = rgb(169, 223, 242) and on small screen the background color = red) but '.text' class is not working on small screen, please help me out.
````

Comment: media queries do not affect selectivity. So, you set the color (to green) in the media query but then  you immediately set it again (to blue).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use @media screen and give max-width with pixel(px). And ".test" should be above of media query, try this one